# Can "trunks of an elephant" mean both its legs and its long nose?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

**The** **long nose of an elephant** is called a trunk.

I feel that I've read things like this in my childhood:

> - The men blindly felt for the elephant. Someone touched its trunks and said, "So long and hard and thick. It seems to be a tree!"
> - Bambo kicked that scrawny little thing out of his way with his trunks.
> - Rani, the large Indian elephant Mr. Fox kept as pet, stomped its trunks in hunger.

which imply an **elephant's legs** are also referred to as trunks. I also thought tree trunks were just like an elephant's legs, so they're called trunks too. However, no dictionary says so. See [trunk](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trunk).

I don't know why but I just can't accept this. I clearly remember I did read things like that in children's stories.

#### Can "trunks of an elephant" mean both its legs and its long nose?

Comment: No. You  misremembered. An individual elephant has a single trunk.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of tusks?

Comment: You are thinking of the teaching story (see **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant))** in which a group of blind men in a room with an elephant draw erroneous conclusions about what is in the room based upon what they can feel. One, feeling the elephant's leg, concludes that it is the _trunk_ of a tree. (If you were told this story as a child, your parents are to be commended.)

Answer (score 1):

An elephant is considered to have a single

> **trunk**

which is often considered to be its *nose*

[image]

The descriptor also has an anatomical meaning

> **trunk** - a person's or animal's body apart from the limbs and head.

So, anatomically an elephant might be thought to have *two trunks*.

As a play on words, an elephant might travel with a luggage "**trunk**"

[image]
<sub>(source: [gawkerassets.com](https://cache.gawkerassets.com/assets/images/4/2009/12/500x_elephant-luggage.jpg))</sub>

but none of these would have the meaning of **trunk** referring to **legs** or **limbs**